# updating array in gtm dataLayer

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a gtm variable that uses a data layer variable for cart lineitems.

```
 dataLayer = [{
 'cartLineitems': [
    {'productCode':'test1','quantity':1},
    {'productCode':'test2','quantity':1},
    {'productCode':'test3','quantity':1}
]
 }];
```

When the cart is updated, I am setting a custom event 'onCartUpdate' and updating the dataLayer with the new cart lineitems array.  This is working correctly when the quantity is changed - the new gtm variable shows the first element of the array with the updated quantity.

```
dataLayer.push({
       'event': 'onCartUpdate',
       'cartLineitems': [
            {'productCode':'test1','quantity':2}},
            {'productCode':'test2','quantity':1}},
            {'productCode':'test3','quantity':1}
    });
```

However, when a customer deletes an item from the cart, gtm doesn't seem to see that the array now has less elements. In the debugger, it shows the data layer having the newest version with 2 items and then it has "Data Layer values after this Message:" and shows the original values.  The value showing up in the Variables tab is the version with 3 items.

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'onCartUpdate',
   'cartLineitems': [
        {'productCode':'test1','quantity':2}},
        {'productCode':'test2','quantity':1}}
});
```

Does anyone know how to properly update an datalayer variable that is an array?

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out... It has to do with the version of the variable: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/data-layer-variable-versions-explained/

I had it set as version 2 which is what it is by default which must only concatenate the objects when you update them rather than totally overwriting the object.  I switched to version 1 and it's working like I want now.

Comment: Naming these different behaviors "versions" is a very bad decision from Google IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use "_clear: true" to rewrite the array values.

From this post [Two simple data model tricks](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/two-simple-data-model-tricks/)